# How to pass commands to a program running in a separate shell using fabric?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I have a program which spawns a shell of its own, I further need to be able to pass commands in that shell. 
For example - 
local(command_which_spawns_new_shell)
Now in this new_shell
I would like to run commands like 'ls' etc... and finally exit from the program or shell. 
When I execute local on this command currently, the program halts after opening up the shell, how can i capture the shell handle and pass further pass commands to it before I exit from the shell?

An example would be 
local(ftp hostname)
and then execute commands like 
lcd 
cd
ls etc... 
FTP is only an example here, the command I will be running spawns a new shell.

Comment: A [mcve] would do much to make this answerable.

Comment: Have you tried running `local(command_in_your_spawned_shell, shell=command_which_spawns_new_shell)`?